# Помогите сделать календарь

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем привет, хочу сделать календарь на Android чтобы нужные даты были в кружечках.
Мне нужно разобрать лишь с тем как сделать их в кружечках, дальше сам, спасибо

Пример того что нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что у меня уже есть, использовал я CalendarView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете воспользоватся готовыми решениями, например https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View Вот список с примерами https://medium.com/@Patel_Prashant_/android-custom-calendar-with-events-fa48dfca8257